# Apache Cordova no construye el proyecto en Android

Tags: nodejs, web, apk, apache-cordova

paso a comentarles, tengo instalado lo siguiente:
Java 8
Gradle 6.8.3
Android Studio 2022.3.1
Apache Maven 3.9.3

Mi problema es que, por alguna razón, cuando intento construir el proyecto me toma como versión del gradle la 7.6, la cual no es compatible con Java 8, si no con Java 11, las variables de Entorno están bien colocadas con sus respectivas rutas, cabe alcarar que anteriormente tenía instalada una versión mas nueva de Gradle la cual desinstale para instalar esta (Ya que claramente la anterior no era compatible) Les dejo lo que me tira el CMD, si alguno me pudiera dar una mano sería de gran ayuda, muchas gracias.

C:\Users\juanc\apps\proyecto>cordova build
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'HelloCordova'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed
> a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\juanc\apps\proyecto\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\juanc\apps\proyecto\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug